# After boot repair, Windows does not boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

Following are the steps till I purchased my computer

1. Installed windows 7
2. Installed Ubuntu
3. There was no boot option, and ubuntu automatically boot, leaving me no option to boot my windows
4. I used windows repair to repair MBR or whatever it is
5. Now, ubuntu does not boot, there is no option to boot ubuntu
6. Finally, I used boot repair disc.
7. Now, there are options for windows and ubuntu.
8. ubuntu boot properly.
9. Windows boot but there is blank PURPLE screen after that

Here is the link:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/12095051

Please help

Comment: are there two entries for windows? None of them work?

Comment: yes there are two entries for windows and none of them works..

Comment: @Ron.. kindly help in resolving this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)